# Excel VBA loop to store value in different cell on button click

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I currently have a worksheet in which I am storing my company's accounts eg. all transfers made (money coming in and going out). I simply require a button which when clicked will save the current date in a cell and next to it the amount "Total" of the company bank balance. I intend to click the button at the end of each month as to record all balances for a particular date. I am having trouble with moving to the next cell to store date and amount for the next month.

An example of what i am trying to achieve

Total (Cell B8) = $100 (**Month 1**)

On Button_1 click

Cell A1 = Current Date
Cell A2 = $100 (Cell B8)

Total (Cell B8) = $200 (**Month 2**) (New amount as money has come in)

On Button_1 click <------ This should not change the amount in A1 and A2

Cell B1 = Current Date

Cell B2 = $200 (Cell B8)

etc. for ever month thereafter

My code:

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim Cell As Integer
Dim SelectedCell As String

For i = 1 To 10
    Cell = 4
    SelectedCell = CStr(Cell)
    Range("C" + SelectedCell).Value = Range("C38").Value
    Cell = Cell + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking a) for help with a problem in the code you've written b) for someone to write the code for you *or* c) how to click a button?

Comment: If it's a), then please [post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sub Button2_Click()


Dim Cell As Integer
Dim SelectedCell As String



For i = 1 To 10

Cell = 4
SelectedCell = CStr(Cell)
Range("C" + SelectedCell).Value = Range("C38").Value
Cell = Cell + 1

Next i

I need help with the code, sorry i wast clear about that. I have tried a for loop, do while and one kick ass if statement. None which seem to work. I am not able to edit my question as to include the code so had to paste it here.

Comment: Why do you need VBA for this?  It sounds like this would be just a simple `SUMIF` on the worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, you are having trouble with moving to the next cell to store date and amount at that date.

Assume that you have stored current balance at B8.

Please try below code

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim col_num As Integer

col_num = 1

Do Until Cells(1, col_num).Value = ""

    col_num = col_num + 1

Loop

Cells(1, col_num).Value = Date
Cells(2, col_num).Value = Range("B8").Value

End Sub
```